# find the json path for a specific value using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

how to find the json path for a specific value using javascript

```
var data = {
    key1: {
        children: {
            key2:'value',
            key3:'value',
            key4: value
        }, 
    key5: 'value'
}
```

expected result from the above `data.key1.children.key3`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With `JSON.parse()` and `myVal['key']` you can go everywhere

Answer (score 0):

var str = "key3";
data["key1"]["children"][str];

Answer (score 0):

This function returns all available paths in your(any) object:
Using this function you can get
`["key1.children.key2", "key1.children.key3", "key1.children.key4", "key1.key5"]`

```
function allPaths(root) {
  let stack = [];
  let result = [];

  // checks if object
  const isObject = value => typeof value === "object";

  stack.push(root);
  while (stack.length > 0) {
    let node = stack.pop();
    if (isObject(node)) {
      Object.entries(node).forEach(([childNodeKey, childNodeValue]) => {
        if (isObject(childNodeValue)) {
          const newObject = Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(childNodeValue).map(([cnk, cnv]) => {
              return [`${childNodeKey}.${cnk}`, cnv];
            })
          );
          stack.push(newObject);
        } else {
          stack.push(`${childNodeKey}`);
        }
      })
    } else {
      result.push(node);
    }
  }
  return result.reverse();
}
```

Let me know in the comments if it was helpful for you